how to form adjoint operator of 2nd order partial in 2 variables operator

The following and attached above is from the book 'Orthogonal Polynomials of Several Variables' by Charles F.Dunkl and Yuan Xu.
When i write here i will often replace the greek or whatever u call it symbols by a,b, c  etc. in particular let alpha=a,beta=b,gamma or looks like a v or whatever u call it by g.
With regard to the inserted picture and weighting given there in (2.7.10) and the operator $L_{a,b,g}$ written below his proposition 2.7.3 to form the adjoint from integration by parts i take the 2nd order ops just as they are and reverse the sign of the first derivative terms and let it operate on the particular coefficient term of that part of the diff op times $W_{a,b,c}(u,v)f$ for arbitrary $f(u,v)$. When all is done divide by $W_{a,b,c}$ and the result should be the same operator operating on f. This is all assuming the intervening integrated terms vanish in the interim which i did not check real carefully but assuming the region of integration is the x,y plot figure 2.7.1 shown but with u on x axis and v on y axis as shown in the attached figure 2.7.1 between the 2 straight lines and the curve $v=u^2/4$ i think they do vanish. Now of course the 2nd order op's came out the same automatically and $g_u$ agreed but first order coeff of $g_v$ did not. I obtained instead (2gv+2bv+2av+5v-3bu+3au+2g+1)
as coefficient of the first derivative wrt v term in the adjoint operator. The adjoint coeff for that was $4(b-a)u$ larger than the original. So am i doing something wrong or is the author in error by claiming $L_{a,b,g}$ is self-adjoint 2nd order diffop. In addition in his eigenvalue equation (2.7.12) for the leading term came out same but the coefficient of n came out opposite his definition below (2.7.11) ; that is i find that all terms have a minus sign fronting them.

To make it simple without having to go thru all that writing above. In general to find the adjoint of a 2nd order diffeq within an integral with a certain
weighting take the 2nd order op's just as they are and reverse the sign of the first order ones and let it operate on w*f where w is the weighting and f is
a function of the pertinent  variables. That should result in the weighting w times the same operator acting on f if the operator is self adjoint and the
integrated terms vanish at the boundaries of integral in the usual case. Is that correct ?

I think in the one variable case one can write an operator as $d (d g/dx)/dx$ to automatically be in self adjoint form. I don't know what would be the case of how to write as self adjoint 2nd order partial diffeq.

to save on the dog work i used maxima to take the derivatives and maxima is not always known not to make errors. Depending on what others say i can do it manually without a lot of trouble. other than that i will assume maxima did it correct.

Actually i believe to come out as self adjoint in the 2nd order one variable case it can be written as $w^{-1}d(d {f(x})/dx)/dx$ if the weighting, w , in the integral is not unity for arbitrary choice of $f(x)$, that is assuming integrated parts vanish. In the 2 variable case it could be written self adjoint as $w^{-1}( d(d(fx)/dx)/dx+d(d (fy)/dy)/dy+d(d (fxy)/dx)/dy++d(d(fxy)/dy)/dx)$ for any choices of functions fx,fy,fxy assuming all integrated parts using integration by parts vanish at the boundaries. Would you all agree ?

I think for arbitrary number of variables a general way of writing the general linear 2nd order partial diff operator in self-adjoint form where the subscripts $i$ such as in $(...){i}$ denote differentiation of what is to it's left with respect to the $i'th$ variable and $w$ is weighting in the integral.The $g[i],g[i,!j]$ denote arbitrary functions of the variables which are unique, can be different, according to the $[i]$ or $ [i,j]$ combination within square brackets.$w^{-1}\left(\sum{i} (g[i] f_{i}){i}+\sum{j>i}\left( (g[i,! j] f_{i}){j}+(g[i,j] f{j})_{i}  \right)\right)$

did not have enough characters left to write it above but if not obvious $f$ is the function upon which the operator is applied and there are conditions assumed that all pertinent integrated parts in integration by parts vanish at the integration region boundaries.

I find upon further trials that his 2nd order operator in, just below, Proposition 2.7.3 MUST be error. The error is in his coefficient for u in coefficient of $g_v$ has a minus sign fronting the $(b-a)$ which should not be there but should just be $(b-a)$ without the minus fronting it. And with that correction his expression just below (2.7.11) for $
\lambda_{k,n}^{a,b,g}$ is also incorrect in that here should be a minus sign fronting the beginning n... terms.That is it should be $\lambda_{k,n}^{a,b,g}=-n(n+2g+b+a+2)-k(k+b+a+1)$. Also on rhs (2.7.11) there should be no minus sign fronting it.

These errors in the book are just an example of an issue far to common. Does it really bother others as it does me when well known and respected authorities publish books and articles with so many
math errors. Seems to me there has been no proof reading or certainly not sufficient. And some of these are meant to be used as college texts. It's difficult and time consuming enough to follow as is if there were no errors. When trying to understand and finally figure i don't really understand when i can't get his answer and after much more exasperation  finally conclude is error-what a time waste.

And not just simple  typo errors. Though those are also often much too numerous. Why let such go to final publish. Since i am a slow reader and thinker then if i found that many errors then for sure they could correct in little time and effort before publish. And if i can find that many errors in such amount of time for sure there are many others elsewhere or in parts of the book i skipped or scan read lightly or not in much detail. I do Not mean to imply that i did not get anything or made a mistake by reading any of these. Still far too many errors that they should correct before publishing.

For example has anyone read any of the following.'Orthogonal Polynomials of Several Variables by C. F. Dunkl , 'Unitary Symmetry and Combinatorics, World Scientific, 2008 by J. Louck 'Applications of Unitary'Symmetry and Combinatorics by J `Louck
Lie Groups and Lie Algebras for Physicists by R. Hermann
Symplectic Geometry,Wigner-Weyl-Moyal 'Calculus,andQuantum Mechanics in Phase Space by Maurice A. de Gosson
'Maximal quantum mechanical symmetry: Projective representations of the inhomogeneous symplectic group by S G. Low Journal of Mathematical Physics 55, 022105 (2014);
